# How to open a window without "close" button?

Tags: window-manager, window-buttons

In a script I want to open a window which is missing the "close" button in the title bar, so that it can't be accidentally be closed, but still has the "minimize" and "maximize" buttons.

Is this possible? Maybe via some window manager arguments?

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 with Unity.

Comment: May I ask what is the use case?

Comment: At first this is supposed to work with gnome-terminal and xfce4-terminal. I want to run a command line tool which takes a very long time to finish (MrBayes phylogeny) and want to prevent someone accidentally closing the window. Maybe this is also applicable for other windows when needed.

Comment: I don't think it is possible from a script, but maybe others will have an idea.

Comment: There must be a way as the `update-manager` also only got a minimize button.

Comment: From an application you can do this, GTK+ has options for this.

Comment: So can I do it for gnome-terminal?

Comment: Not unless you write a GTK+ application with an embedded terminal emulator. I think it doesn't worth the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a little workaround I found the `Window Rules` option in `CompizConfig-Settings-Manager` where I put `xfce4-terminal` (that I generally don't use and installed just for that purpose) to "Non Closable Windows".

Now I can start shell scripts using `xfce4-terminal` to execute commands

> `xfce4-terminal -e "command you want to run"`

that mustn't be terminated by accidentally clicking the close button by unexperienced users.